# what dose build mean in the code from rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I was following the blog [devise in rails](https://mackenziechild.me/12-in-12/1/). I found some codes like this:

```
def new
  @link = current_user.links.build
end
```

And I wonder what the build mean and its purpose ? Does it from the devise or ActiveRecord Model ?

Answer (score 2):

It is from `ActiveRecord`.

In your example, `current_user.links.build` initializes a new instance of `Link` with its `user_id` set. (The instance is initialized but not saved to the database.)

For more information, please see the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build)